# Send email on matching cell value in a Sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to send email when value of column 8 matched column 3 for all the rows in a google script .

```
function sendEmailNotification() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var lrow=ss.getLastRow()
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();

  for (var i = 2; i < lrow; i++)
  {
    if (sheet.getRange(i, 8).getValue() = sheet.getRange(i, 3).getValue())

      var emailSubject =  'Value of ' + sheet.getRange(i, 1).getDisplayValue() + ' triggered, now pending your attention';
    var emailBody = 'Person1 has approved the item on row ' + ' of spreadsheet "' + '".\n\n';
    emailBody += 'To open the spreadsheet, click this link: ' + ss.getUrl() + '\n\n';
    emailBody += '(this is an automatically sent message)';

    MailApp.sendEmail("sdas22@gmail.com", emailSubject, emailBody);
;  }}
```

Comment: Hi Subhati-Das, what is the exact problem you're encountering?

Comment: I applied syntax based indentation to your code... There are two major issues. Review JavaScript operators (specifically assignment and comparison) and when one uses "curly braces"

Comment: Look at StackOverflow [Applying a formula to all cells in a column, unless equals x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52680239/applying-a-formula-to-all-cells-in-a-column-unless-equals-x). I just posted some code that would work for your scenario.

Comment: @SUBHAJIT DAS Ole EH Dufour is quite right to ask -  just what is your problem? But assuming that you're new to this, and copying and pasting from other sources, and trying to make sense of it all... then I strongly urge you to use Logger.log(); in your code to track the values of statements as you go. Of course, Debug is also pretty handy to when the whole thing goes phut.

Comment: I am getting an error : 

ReferenceError: Function function getValue() {/* */} can not be used as the left-hand side of assignment or as an operand of ++ or -- operator. (line 9, file "Code")DetailsDismiss

Comment: @SUBHAJIT DAS Just for future reference, the details of the ReferenceError were very important (though not unexpected). It is something that should have been included in your original question. Perhaps next time round, you will have learned about providing as much information as possible.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is the IF statement

This is yours which does not work and which is generating an error message

```
if (sheet.getRange(i, 8).getValue() = sheet.getRange(i, 3).getValue())
```

This is mine which does work

```
 if ((sheet.getRange(i, 8).getValue()) == (sheet.getRange(i, 3).getValue())){

    }
```

A couple of things to note.

- The comparison operator is "==" rather than "="
- The each of the getValue statements are encapsulated in brackets
- There are no "curly brackets" to indicate the purpose of the IF statement. This is particular important.

There's also semicolon on the last line that seem out of place.

---

This is my version of your code - which runs

```
function sendEmailNotification() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var lrow=ss.getLastRow()
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();

  for (var i = 2; i < lrow; i++)
  {

    if ((sheet.getRange(i, 8).getValue()) == (sheet.getRange(i, 3).getValue())){

        var emailSubject =  'Value of ' + sheet.getRange(i, 1).getDisplayValue() + ' triggered, now pending your attention';
        var emailBody = 'Person1 has approved the item on row ' + ' of spreadsheet "' + '".\n\n';
        emailBody += 'To open the spreadsheet, click this link: ' + ss.getUrl() + '\n\n';
        emailBody += '(this is an automatically sent message)';
        MailApp.sendEmail("sdas22@gmail.com", emailSubject, emailBody);
    }
  }
}
```